# How can I optimize a query in a large MySQL table without any joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

How can I optimize this single query from a single large-ish table (~75M rows)?

```
SELECT
    log_id
FROM
    score
WHERE
    class_id IN (17,395)
ORDER BY date_reverse
LIMIT 10000;
```

I pull the most recent 10k records for a particular set of classes so that I can quickly know if they already exist or not during a larger import script.

I think I've indexed appropriately but this query lasts anywhere from 5-50 seconds!

Let me know if you need anything else.

```
EXPLAIN
    SELECT
        log_id
    FROM
        score
    WHERE
        class_id IN (17,395)
    ORDER BY date_reverse
    LIMIT 10000;

*** row 1 ***
          table:  score
           type:  range
  possible_keys:  class_id,score_multi_2,class_id_date_reverse,score_multi_5
            key:  class_id_date_reverse
        key_len:  4
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  1287726
          Extra:  Using where; Using index; Using filesort

CREATE TABLE `score` (
  `log_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `process_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_type_id` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_reverse` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`log_id`,`class_id`),
  KEY `class_id` (`class_id`),
  KEY `profile_id` (`profile_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `status_type_id` (`status_type_id `),
  KEY `status_type_id_date` (`status_type_id`,`date`),
  KEY `class_status_type_id_date_log_id` (`class_id`,`status_type_id`,`date`,`log_id`),
  KEY `date_reverse` (`date_reverse`),
  KEY `class_id_date_reverse` (`class_id`,`date_reverse`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `class_id_date_reverse_log_id` (`class_id`,`date_reverse`,`log_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the fastest way to run this query is to bite the bullet and allow a sort on 20,000 rows.  The query I have in mind is:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT log_id
       FROM score
       WHERE class_id = 17
       ORDER BY date_reverse
       LIMIT 10000
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT log_id
       FROM score
       WHERE class_id = 395
       ORDER BY date_reverse
       LIMIT 10000
      )
     ) s
ORDER BY date_reverse
LIMIT 10000;
```

For this query, you want the composite index on `score(class_id, date_reverse, log_id)`.  Each subquery should use this index quite effectively.  However, the final sort will need to use file sort.

Comment: I suspect Gordon is right, but I might try something else too. Change your unique key to a primary key and reverse the order to (`class_id`,log_id`). Then try running the query as before. Assuming this is on the Innodb storage engine, MySQL will include the primary key values with each secondary index, making your date_reverse index effectively (class_id, log_id) + date_reverse. I'm not sure that it would make a difference to the optimizer, but it is possible that it might. I'd at least be curious enough to give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks @evanv, do you mean like so: `ALTER TABLE score DROP UNIQUE KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (class_id,log_id);`

Comment: @Ryan, yes. Again, I am not sure if it will help or not. But I would give it a shot. Also, change your class_id key to log_id if you do give this a shot.

Comment: At the end of the day both Gordon and evan's proposed solutions did little to impact the result time. I'm accepting Gordon's answer because I ended up archiving a huge portion of this table to make it work and no longer have the ability to test additional solutions.